# Selecting only data that is inside apostrophes from a column.

Tags: sql, select

I have a column which contains a string such as:

```
 Approved By Smith, John For  'Core Authoring Files'
```

I want my select to only return

```
 Core Authoring Files
```

Is there a way to only select the data that is inside the apostrophes?

Comment: What database are you using.  More than likely, you'll have to use a programming language such as PHP to get the inner string, but there might be a custom library for a specific database that might help out, or it could be done as a db function

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but the substring is implemented slightly different in different database systems so you may have to modify this a bit depending on what server you are using.

```
select 
substring(column, charindex("'", column, 0) as begin), charindex("'", column, begin + 1) - begin)) as thestring
from yourTable;
```

the way this works is to use the charindex function to find the position of the first quote character in the string, then find the second quote character in the string starting at the character after the first quote and subtracting those positions to get the length of the string you wish to extract.  Those two numbers are passed to the substring function to get substring (column, startposition, length).

Hope this helps

EDIT

I would like to take a second to dissuade you from allowing unescaped quote characters to be stored in your database.  This is a situation begging for a sql injection attack.  If you are unfamiliar, please research sql injection before going too far down this path.

Comment: I don't see why unescaped quotes in the database are a problem. Once they're in the database, they're not threat. It's unescaped quotes in user input that are a potential danger.

Comment: because when you manipulate the text using sql statements as I am doing in this case, it is possible that the string will be interpreted by the sql interpreter and once it hits the imbedded code will execute it.

Comment: Awesome... Thanks.. I took some of your logic and made this work.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter and it submitted.  select replace
(substring(transmit_processing_msg, charindex('''', transmit_processing_msg, 0), 50),'''','')
from transmit_manifest_detail

Comment: I don't know what DBMS you're writing this for, but I can't imagine there's a database in the world that would interpret the contents of a string without an explicit call to do so. In application code, sure, but not in the database itself. Otherwise, a malicious user could just escape the escape character and you're back with a SQL injection attack.

Comment: Well, lets see.  I have seen this demonstrated on SQL Server 2005 and 2008 fully patched.  On Oracle versions from 8 through 11, on MySQL, on Sybase, and so I imagine it wouldn't be difficult to reproduce it on most other full up SQL style DBMSs.  If you choose not to believe, I have no problem with that.  Go on writing your code allowing storage of single quoted data.  Hopefully you will never run into the issue and life will go on rosey.  If you have sensitive data, maybe you should be safe rather than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql this is pretty simple using the regexp_replace string operator.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 
      regexp_replace(title, E'.*\'\(.*\)\'.*', E'\\1') AS result 
   FROM
      items) x 
WHERE
   result IS NOT null;
```